# GraphQL: How to publish subscription from a scheduled Agenda job

Tags: node.js, graphql, publish-subscribe, apollo-server, agenda

My question is also asked [Trigger Apollo Subscription at a later time with Agenda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56098671/trigger-apollo-subscription-at-a-later-time-with-agenda), but there is no answer and I do not have enough reputation to comment there. Wasn't sure what to do, so I am posting a new question.

I am working with graphql-yoga and use pubsub to trigger subscriptions. I have a mutation, which receives pubsub as a context argument. From there, I can publish my subscription via pubsub.publish. This is working fine.

I also schedule jobs via agenda (https://github.com/agenda/agenda). When those jobs run later, I update the database. This is also working.

My problem is that when I update the database in an agenda job, I need to also publish the database updates to subscriptions. I do not know how to get access to pubsub in my agenda function.

I tried including my pubsub object that I already have in the mutation with the data that I deliver to the job, in hopes that I could access pubsub later. But that doesn't work (unsurprisingly).

I can't find any documentation, and the similar stackoverflow question that I found (linked above) doesn't have any responses.

Does anyone know if it is possible to trigger a Subscription from an Agenda job?

Comment: My latest idea is to use Axios to make a POST request from the agenda job back to the server, so that it can update the db and trigger the subscription normally. But this seems kudgy.

Comment: You should be able to use the same PubSub you use inside your mutations, even if you're running a separate process, as long as you use an [implementation other than the default in-memory one](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-subscriptions#pubsub-implementations). Is that the case?

Comment: in app.js, I have const pubsub - new PubSub(), and PubSub is required from graphql-yoga, so I guess that is a default implementation(?). It isn't clear to me how I access pubsub from inside the agenda job. The mutations have pubsub included as a parameter to the functions because teh server is set up with pubsub context.

Comment: I solved my problem by using Axios to make a POST request to do a mutation. Within the mutation, the subscription is published. This works, but I'm still not sure it was the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `agenda`, but I suspect it runs jobs in a process that's separate from your GraphQL server. The default `PubSub` implementation just uses [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) and that won't work across multiple processes. So you should utilize an implementation that will persist the subscriptions somewhere, like a database, a key-value store, a message queue, etc. Create a module and export the PubSub instance:

```
// pubsub.js

const { RedisPubSub } = require('graphql-redis-subscriptions')
const Redis = require('ioredis')

const options = {
  // redis client options
};

module.exports = new RedisPubSub({
  publisher: new Redis(options),
  subscriber: new Redis(options)
})
```

Then you can just import that module inside both your GraphQL resolvers and your jobs and call `publish` and `subscribe` as needed.